# Is there local Accepted Tunneling Solution To Test Facebook Webhooks

Tags: webhooks, ngrok, facebook-webhooks, whatsapi, localtunnel

I am integrating WhatsApp with Django application that I am still running locally to send WhatsApp which is working fine.

However to receives messages from Facebook it needs a webhook that I have implemented using Django  since I am still building the application locally. on my laptops I am using Tunneling solutions Ngrok and LocalTunnel to expose the application online so that Facebook can send incoming messages to my App onto my laptop but Facebook is rejecting URLs that are I created using Ngrok and LocalTunnel with error message below:

> The url https://2y7y-56-897-3-457.eu.ngrok.io/apv/facebook has been identified as malicious and/or abusive.
>
> The url https://great-finds-comes-78-673-8-897.loca.lt/apv/facebook has been identified as malicious and/or abusive.

I have two questions:

1. Has anyone been successful using Ngrok and Localtunnel while building locally on Facebook webhooks?
2. what other tools are there that are available on windows to achieve this? I don't have a dedicated domain name yet and dedicated cloud/online platform where I can host the app yet.

The other alternative solutions I have seen that have been mentioned, it's the Ultrahook though the client is available as a Ruby gem that I have failed to get running on windows:

I was following this question: [Can i use localhost as a URL Callback in a messenger webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583538/can-i-use-localhost-as-a-url-callback-in-a-messenger-webhook)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngrok with option `--region us` as mentionned in this issue : https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/427